# Get datagrid column value - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with two columns; well and workover. 
WPF:

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="PrintReport1" ItemsSource="{Binding TableResults}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" 
IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Well" Binding="{Binding WellName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"  >

            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="dg_MouseLeftButtonDown_Injector" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Recommendated Workover Type" Binding="{Binding WorkoverRecommendation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"  >                                                               </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

There is a `eventsetter` event for the first column by which I can get the column value when user clicks on a particular cell as:

```
private void dg_MouseLeftButtonDown_Injector(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    dynamic dataObject = cell.DataContext;
    string InjectorName = dataObject.WellName;
    //do something...
}
```

My question is how can I get the corresponding second column value?
For example, if the `datagrid` looks like this:

```
Well  Workover

Well1     ABC

Well2     DEF
```

and if user clicks on "Well2" cell, how do I get corresponding Workover value too; "DEF"?

Comment: `dataObject.WorkoverRecommendation`

Comment: @ASh thnx. that was easy!!

Answer (score -1):

```
dataObject.WorkoverRecommendation
```